# How can I figure out what kind of phone is consuming an ASP.NET web service?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, mobile, sniffing

I'm working on a project that has a variety of mobile devices consuming an ASP.NET SOAP-based web service using native phone apps on each platform (iOS, Android, WP7).

A very late feature request has been to log which types of phones are being used to access the web service.

Ordinarily I would just add an additional parameter to the web service methods to specify which type of phone is making the request and have the value hard-coded into the individual apps. However, like I said it's very late into the project to be doing this. I can do it in a future phase but it's nontrivial to update phone apps after they're live in their respective stores so I'd like to make the update ASAP if the feature request goes forward.

The other problem is we already have some integration partners working with the service and so I'm reticent to change the API this late into the game for that reason as well.

Is there any way to "sniff out" which kinds of phones are calling the web service? Consider that the requests are coming from native phone apps (not web browsers), at least some of which I will have complete control over.

Answer (score 0):

what jumps into my mind is using the Tracing to check if you get different request from those apps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb885203.aspx, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx, hope this helps